# upload image to firebase cloud storage in laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

HTML script

```
<label class="form-control-label" for="image">Image</label>
<input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="form-control">
```

**UploadController**

```
$image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$storage = new StorageClient();
$bucket = $storage->bucket('packagesIcons');
$bucket->upload(
    fopen($image, 'r'),
    [
        'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
    ]
);
return back();
```

I have been trying to upload file to my project in firebase but it keeps displaying **null** in **$image**

**Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null**

Can anybody help me in this how to upload it correctly, I m stuck here...

Comment: Could you share your entire form to upload file?

Comment: @TomaszBucko thnks but now done using js...

Comment: I would like to know if the enctype of form is multipart or not. It seems that the enctype is not multipart. please check it.

Comment: Or can you share your js code to upload file?

Comment: yes that also i have checked twice but didn't work as i m new to firebase & didn't found any reference on uploading files using PHP.. finally followed js to work it. done brother no need now thanks @TomaszBucko